# How can I install Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 tools on visual studio community 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I want to create an app for Windows Phone 8.1 using Visual Studio Community 2015 but I'm having trouble installing the tools. Everytime I try to install it, it says "This setup supports the following switches: /? Display this usage text /H ...."
When I click OK nothing happens.

Comment: I think you have downloaded the wrong tools(?) - it sounds like you've downloaded a tool meant to be run via the command line.

Can you provide a bit more info with what you're trying to achieve, etc.?

Comment: I have downloaded VS Community 2015 and I want to make phone apps for Windows Phone 8/8.1. Is that a way I can create these apps on VS 2015 ?

Comment: Hmm, what tools did you download and is that when you double-click them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- open Visual Studio Community 2015 iso file
- open "vs_community.exe"
- Modify
- check Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 tools https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlYUX.png
- update
- open VS and create your new app